# Accurate modeling with the psping -l parameter?

Tags: networking, pstools

I'm in the process of setting up a [psping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx) job to allow me to test the performance of some new network based applications in my environment.

I'm a little hung up on the `-l` argument for specifying the request size. Should I be expressing this as the size of the request per call to my application?

For example I create a 30 megabyte output file which needs to be transferred. Should it be the 30m or the length of an individual (reassembled / fragmented ?) packet?